# Hide element in IE in custom NewForm.aspx or EditForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, custom-list, hide-elements

In custom **NewForm.aspx** or **EditForm.aspx**, the ribbon is hidden and the following is added:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="colFull" id="attachmentsOnClient">
    <span dir="ltr">
        <input type="file" name="fileupload0"  id="onetidIOFile" class="ms-fileinput" size="56" title="Name"></input>
    </span>
    <div id="ieAttachBtn">
        <input name="Button1" type="button" value="Attach" onclick='OkAttach()' style="width: 6em; height: 1.7em" />
        <span id="idSpace"></span>
    </div>
    <table>
        <tr id="idAttachmentsRow">
            <td nowrap="true" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel" width="20%">
                <SharePoint:FieldLabel ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Attachments" runat="server"/>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="80%">
                <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="AttachmentsField" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Attachments" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u','AttachmentsField','Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Attachments')}"/>
                <script>
                    var elm = document.getElementById(&quot;idAttachmentsTable&quot;);
                    if (elm == null || elm.rows.length == 0)
                    document.getElementById(&quot;idAttachmentsRow&quot;).style.display=&apos;none&apos;;
                </script>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>                            
</div>
```

`ieAttachBtn` is only needed in IE. It works without it in Chrome and Edge. Is there a way to show/hide this `<div>` based on browser?

I inserted the following code after `PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead`, the alert works but the `.getElementById().style.display` does not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) {
    alert('This is IE');
    document.getElementById("ieAttachBtn").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    alert('This is not IE');
    document.getElementById("ieAttachBtn").style.display = "none";
}   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using the code below.

```
<script language="javascript">
function hideIEBtn() {
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        $(&quot;div[id=ieAttachBtn]&quot;).show();
    } else {
        $(&quot;div[id=ieAttachBtn]&quot;).hide();
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    hideIEBtn();
});
```